# why not delete incomplete file in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im useing onCancelled() in asynctask for delete incomplete file but when download incomplete file donnt delete it.
(file is music)

why not delete incomplete file in the following code?

my api is 8

this is my code:

```
public class ZiaratMatn4 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 MediaPlayer mp;
 ImageButton btndownziarat;
 ImageButton btnplayziarat;
 SeekBar seek_bar;
 Handler seekHandler = new Handler();
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
  private static String file_url = "http://upir.ir/files92be/2eda2a6a5434.mp3";
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ziaratmatn);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.fromFile(audioFile));
    btnplayziarat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnplayziarat);
    btnplayziarat.setOnClickListener(this);
    btndownziarat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btndownziarat);
    btndownziarat.setOnClickListener(this);     
    getInit();
 seekUpdation();
}
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File audioFile = new File(sdcard.getPath() + "/EBKH/basem-vares.mp3");
 public void getInit() {
     if(audioFile.exists())
        {
     seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbziarat);
 seek_bar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
 }}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btnplayziarat :
        if(audioFile.exists())
        {
                if(mp!=null)
                {
                   if(mp.isPlaying())
                   {
                      mp.pause();
                      btnplayziarat.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                   }   
                   else
                   {
                     mp.start();
                     btnplayziarat.setImageResource(R.drawable.puse);
                   }}}
        break;
    case R.id.btndownziarat :
        if(!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/EBKH/basem-vares.mp3").exists())          
             new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
       break;   
 }}
 Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation();
        }
    };
    public void seekUpdation() {
        if(audioFile.exists())
        {
        seek_bar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }}
 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
switch (id) {
case progress_bar_type:
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("در حال دانلود،لطفا صبور باشید...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setMax(100);
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
    return pDialog;
default:
    return null;
}
 }

 class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    File file= new File("/sdcard/EBKH/basem-vares.mp3");
    file.delete();
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
try {
    URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
    conection.connect();
    int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/EBKH/basem-vares.mp3");
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    long total = 0;
    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
}
return null;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure as to what is going on here but what **might** help is adding a `finally{}` block at the end which checks if the total bytes read is equal to the length of the file. If not, delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're never cancelling the AsyncTask!!! You need to call `cancel()` on the AsyncTask object, but to do that you need to keep the instance in a variable first.

So first, keep the instance of the AsyncTask, so declare the task in your class

```
DownloadFileFromURL downloadTask;
```

When you create the task, assign it to your variable

```
downloadTask = new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
```

And whenever you want to cancel, call this:

```
downloadTask.cancel();
```